# How can my program return to the first command of a loop?

Tags: python, loops

How can my loop branch back to looking for input if there is no work to do?

I'm making a script that essentially asks for 3 or 4 `raw_input` lines, and then does some work based on those, and loops infinitely. However, the `raw_input` lines are choices (I'm looking for them to type one of a few statements). Instead of a mess of booleans and while loops to make sure it's an acceptable statement, I thought it might be easier and cleaner to simply do something like this:

```
if theInput != 'Acceptable Statement' and theInput != 'Another acceptable statement':
    restartLoop()
if theSecondInput != 'Acceptable Statement' and theInput != 'Another acceptable statement':
    restartLoop()
```

And so on, for every input I need. It would abort the current cycle and restart with another, as if it had finished. Since nothing actually happens until all the data is collected and approved, this *shouldn't* cause any problems. I realize this is an alternative:

```
if theInput == 'Acceptable Statement' or theInput == 'Another acceptable statement':
    if theSecondInput == 'Acceptable Statement' or theInput == 'Another acceptable statement':
        doThings()
    else:
        doNothing()
else:
    doNothing()
```

However, I'd like it to end the loop after the input the user gets wrong, instead of asking them 5 questions and eventually telling them they got #2 wrong.

EDIT: Just to be a bit clearer, I still want to infinitely loop (nothing but leaving the shell will leave the loop), I just want to restart the loop without completing. IE, when making many of a product, you are in a loop with a few steps. But, if you perform a step incorrectly, you throw out the faulty product and start over without finishing.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen `continue` will skip the rest of the loop, but not *restart* it .. note OP says: "abort the current cycle and restart with another, as if it had finished."

Comment: @Levon If the looping condition checks to see if valid input was entered they are effectively the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested `if`s will work just fine, and you can make them neater, too:

```
if theInput == 'Acceptable Statement' or theInput == 'Another acceptable statement':
    if theSecondInput == 'Acceptable Statement' or theInput == 'Another acceptable statement':
        doThings()
        break
```

But `continue` will do what you need. I just find the above nicer-looking :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`continue`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#continue) and [`break`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#break) to control the flow of the loop.

```
while True:
   //getInput
   if theInput != AcceptableInput:
      print "Input 1 is wrong."
      continue

   //getInput
   if theInput != AcceptableInput:
      print "Input 2 is wrong."
      continue

   //getInput
   if theInput != AcceptableInput:
      print "Input 3 is wrong."
      continue

   //getInput
   if theInput != AcceptableInput:
      print "Input 4 is wrong."
      continue

   //getInput
   if theInput != AcceptableInput:
      print "Input 5 is wrong."
      continue

   break
```

Comment: So continue "throws out" the current loop cycle and begins a new one, without ending the loop?

Comment: continue stops the current iteration of the loop and starts a new one. break stops the current iteration of the loop and starts executing the code after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The below should surely be enough to do what you want (Note that all of the objects are made up, apart from `next` and the strings).

```
print "Instructions"
while True:
    userresponse = get_some_input()
    if isAcceptable(userresponse):
       store(userresponse)
       print "Good job"
       print next(prompts)
    else:
       print "Awful job"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `continue` in the loop accomplishes what I want. It works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You need a second loop and break the inner loop. Something like this:

```
while True:
  while True:
    # do some fancy stuff
    if (fancy stuff is uncool):
      break
  print "restart"
```

**edit**: To clarify this for you: your `restartLoop()` would be `break`. And replace the condition of the if statement ;)

Answer (score -1):

If you have some sort of termination statement ("quit" or "q") I would suggest something similar to this:

```
while( input != "q" || "quit")
     if statement == "acceptable statement"
          doStuff()
     if statement != "acceptable statement"
          //output error
          input = "q" //this will terminate the loop
```

You could even have a private worker method that checks the input vs acceptable statements. Then you can have your "ifs" to process the input. It also seems like you might want to store what answers you are expecting at what stage of the questions you are. For example...

**Level 1**
Question: Knock Knock
Expected responses: "Who's there?", "I hate jokes.", "What?"

**Level 2**
Question: Boo!
Expected responses: "Boo who?", "Stop"

**Level 3**
Question: Aw, don't cry!
Expected responses: "Haha", "Not funny"

Comment: I don't want to terminate the loop, I want to restart it. Imagine you are making 100s of sandwiches, but you put the wrong type of mustard on one. You don't stop making sandwiches, you just throw out the invalid one and continue the loop.

Comment: You don't have to terminate there then. Instead, just output an the error and let the loop continue listening for a response.